# Pycharm: how to rename (refactor, rename) a variable or parameter WITHIN the scope of the function it exists in

Tags: pycharm, refactoring, rename

Pycharm doesn't seem to understand function scope, when refactor/rename is chosen for a function's variable, it wants file scope, or project scope... I thought visual studio did a great job with C# or C++ for this...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you try pessing `Ctrl + Shift + R` you can see the possible scopes for substituting. Besides the normal scopes the IDE offers, you can define [costum scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-scopes.html) but that works by filtering files not Python constructs. I don't think that what you are asking for is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the information!

Comment: @bad_coder I do "feel" for the OP here: it would be nice to have a "just replace the variable in the current file" shortcut instead of that heavy-ish dialog

Comment: @WestCoastProjects "current file" is a default option of the custom scopes, the problem is if you only want an inner scope because that inner scope can also see the outer scopes. But regardless of file, I use the same variable names for the same items minding name collisions across the project.